White Icons appear on Desktop - all of them .part files - white
I do not know what I did but all of a sudden I have 5 white icons on my right end of the Desktop - all carry the extension .part (png.part/html.part etc.). Do they result from copying screenshots or ?????
Maybe everytime I open my attachment to an email - it creates an Icon on Desktop ??

You've provided no Ubuntu product & release details, so we'd mostly be guessing. Are you using the latest Ubuntu Desktop 24.10? or something else? You mention email; but give no clues as to what MUA (mail program) you're using, why not tell us instead of making us guess details.

did you download something from the internet?... .part may be a partial download ... it would get its correct name after the download completes
